# How to add json from url in databound app in windows 8 application

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to add json from url in the databound app in visual basic 2013 on which i am working..... but I cant find any way how can i do this.

. I want to add data from json url
. second i want to show also image
. image on left side and text on right side.

JSON sample is :

```
{"worldpopulation":[{"titlejson":"Bullish trend observed in KSE with 300 points increase","titledesc":25695,"flag":""}]}
```

How do i get that json to windows phone

I want to load data in this page MainViewmodel.cs

```
    public void LoadData()
        {
            // Sample data; replace with real data
            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });

            this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to consume a service ?

Comment: yes json service from url

Answer (score 0):

You need to have model that is appropriate to your json result.

**The model corresponds to your json result**

you can generate model using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Worldpopulation
{
  public string titlejson { get; set; }
  public int titledesc { get; set; }
  public string flag { get; set; }
}

 public class RootObject 
{
  public List<Worldpopulation> worldpopulation { get; set; }
}
```

> Your viewmodel load data method should invoke the webservice using `HttpClient` to get your `json` result . It will deseralize to your model then you could transfer to your view model

The `LoadData()` Method data consuming service

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");

                var url = "data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={0}&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var yourResult= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data.Result.ToString());
                }
           //Code to map to your view-model object and bind them to view

            }
```

Comment: cant understand there is two files one is main.xaml and other is mainviewmodel.cs where i can write this code

Comment: the data is like that in view model                                                      using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace PhoneApp1.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class City
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "countrycode")]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "population")]
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }
}